# Is it possible use or require a Perl script without executing its statements?

Tags: perl, testing, refactoring

I need to add unit testing to some old scripts, the scripts are all basically in the following form:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# Main code
foo();
bar();

# subs
sub foo {

}
sub bar {

}
```

If I try to 'require' this code in a unit test, the main section of the code will run, where as I want to be able to just test "foo" in isolation.

Is there any way to do this without moving foo,bar into a seperate .pm file?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Another common trick for unit testing scripts is to wrap the body of their code into a 'caller' block:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

unless (caller) {
    # startup code
}

sub foo { ... }
```

When run from the command line, cron, a bash script, etc., it runs normally.  However, if you load it from another Perl program, the "unless (caller) {...}" code does not run.  Then in your test program, declare a namespace (since the script is probably running code in package main::) and 'do' the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package Tests::Script;   # avoid the Test:: namespace to avoid conflicts
                         # with testing modules
use strict;
use warnings;

do 'some_script' or die "Cannot (do 'some_script'): $!";

# write your tests
```

'do' is more efficient than eval and fairly clean for this.

Another trick for testing scripts is to use [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Expect/).  This is cleaner, but is also harder to use and it won't let you override anything within the script if you need to mock anything up.

Comment: If there is a remote possibility that somebody will package your script with PAR (i.e. "pp -o binary script.pl; ./binary") or actually eval it and expect it to run, then *please* don't do this. This gave me lots of worries with perlcritic when I was preparing my YAPC::EU talk.

Comment: To be fair, I don't worry in the slightest about PAR.  Perl 5 has too many flaws for me to remember all of the special cases, particularly for non-core code :(

Comment: @tsee which end is your concern on? Writing scripts in an `unless caller` block? Or running the test by `do or die`?

Answer (score 18):

Assuming you have no security concerns, wrap it in a sub { ... } and eval it:

```
use File::Slurp "read_file";
eval "package Script; sub {" . read_file("script") . "}";

is(Script::foo(), "foo");
```

(taking care that the eval isn't in scope of any lexicals that would be closed over by the script).

Comment: Since one has to run code to test it, there's no special security concern with using eval STRING here.

Answer (score 11):

Ahh, the old "how do I unit test a program" question.  The simplest trick is to put this in your program before it starts doing things:

```
return 1 unless $0 eq __FILE__;
```

`__FILE__` is the current source file.  `$0` is the name of the program being run.  If they are the same, your code is being executed as a program.  If they're different, it's being loaded as a library.

That's enough to let you start unit testing the subroutines inside your program.

```
require "some/program";
...and test...
```

Next step is to move all the code outside a subroutine into `main`, then you can do this:

```
main() if $0 eq __FILE__;
```

and now you can test main() just like any other subroutine.

Once that's done you can start contemplating moving the program's subroutines out into their own real libraries.

Comment: The same gotcha I point out in the comment to Ovid's solution applies here: Try packaging that with PAR::Packer or similar tools.

Comment: @tsee  I'll blow up that bridge when it comes.  ysth's trick is clever though and seems to get around the problem without having to edit the code at all.